# Unable to add columns to data table in R

Tags: r

I am trying to add columns with `""` value to the data table. But getting following error. Can anyone help me here.

Since it is converted to data.table , I am unable to convert.

```
iris_sam <- iris
iris_sam <- as.data.table(iris_sam)
iris_sam[c("new", "New1")] <- ""

Error in `[.data.table`(x, i, which = TRUE) : 
  When i is a data.table (or character vector), the columns to join by must be specified using 'on=' argument (see ?data.table), by keying x (i.e. sorted, and, marked as sorted, see ?setkey), or by sharing column names between x and i (i.e., a natural join). Keyed joins might have further speed benefits on very large data due to x being sorted in RAM.
```

Comment: You should do `iris_sam[, c("new", "New1")] <- ""`

Answer (score 0):

`data.table` uses different syntax, please look into the documentation. For this case you can assign the new columns like this:

```
library(data.table)
iris_sam <- iris
iris_sam <- as.data.table(iris_sam)
iris_sam[j = c("new", "New1") := ""]

head(iris_sam, 5)

#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species new New1
#> 1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa         
#> 2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa         
#> 3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa         
#> 4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa         
#> 5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
```